# after ajax callback, how to alter views exposed form

Tags: ajax, views

Look at my code is there any other way to do this. I tried to change my form element type in my exposed view filter after selecting any dropdown menu and my dsm($form_state) not showing any **[values]** index.

```
function loan_details_filter_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form_state['view']->name == 'hundy_users_detail') {

    // Unset the title and body filter info so that it doesn't print any label.
    /* unset($form['#info']['filter-status']);
    unset($form['#info']['filter-first_name']);
    // Unset the title and body filter
    unset($form['status']);
    unset($form['first_name']); */



    //$updated_form_element_type = !empty($form_state['values']['search_within']) ? 'textfield' : 'hidden';
    $select_options = array(
      'name' => 'Name',
      'loan_status' => 'Loan Status',
    );
    $form['search_within'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Search Criteria'),
      '#options' => $select_options,
      '#default_value' => !empty($form_state['search_within']) ? $form_state['search_within'] : '',
      '#prefix' => '<div class="views-exposed-widget">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#ajax' => array(
        'event' => 'change',
        'callback' => 'ajax_filter_form_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'views-exposed-widget',
      ),
    );

    $form['search_box'] = array(
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#title' => 'Search',
          '#prefix' => '<div class="views-exposed-widget">',
          '#suffix' => '</div>',

    );
  }
  dsm( $form_state );

}
function ajax_filter_form_callback(&$form, &$form_state){
  $form['search_box']['#type'] = 'radio';
   //echo $form['search_box'];
  return $form;

}
```